# ES6 dynamic imports with expressions

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, lit-element

I am trying to dynamically load a module depending on the sub-class' class name. The code could be seen here:

```
const name = this.constructor.name;
import(
  `../../src/components/${name}/View/${name}.js`).then((module) => {
});
```

I am using a mixin with is extended by a sub-class. The mixin resides in node_modules.

Assuming the sub-class resides in `./src/components/ExampleComponent` Is there any way to infer the sub-class' directory from the mixin?

Is there anyway to infer the project root?

Using webpack, webpack is unable to find the template `ExampleComponent/View/ExampleComponent`
 unless the mixin resides inside of the project root.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: May you share the code you’re using?

Comment: You should be able to find it at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anoblet/RenderTemplate/master/RenderTemplate.js

Comment: Keep the link, but to be fair to future users put any relevant code in a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: Are you using Babel to enable dynamic imports?

Comment: The mixin should not need to care about the class that extends it at all. Why do you think you need that path in the first place?

Comment: Edited the original post to add the code that I have. I am not using Babel, but I am using Webpack. The reason why I need the sub-class is because a 'view' is being loaded from inside of the sub-class directory. The code get's loaded into Webpack but on the frontend it requests 'e/View/e.js'.